# Problem with sansmathfonts and dvips

Tags: fonts, texlive, dvips

Hoping that this is not off-topic: the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\begin{document}
$E=\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$
\end{document}
```

produces a correct pdf output when processed with `pdflatex`, as well as a correct dvi file when `latex` is used. (TeXLive2016 on a opensuse machine.) However, after I run `dvips` and open the ps file with `gv` this is the result

[image]

Converting the ps file to a pdf with `ps2pdf` still shows the picture above. My first idea was that the fonts were not properly installed, but `dvips` does not complain tough. Here is its output:

```
This is dvips(k) 5.996 Copyright 2016 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2017.02.13:1139' -> mwe.ps
</usr/share/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro></usr/share/texmf/dvips/base/texps.pro>
. </usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss8.pfb>
</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/sansmathfonts/cmssex10.pfb>
</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss10.pfb>
</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/sansmathfonts/cmssmi10.pfb>[1]
```

Any suggestion is welcome `:-)`

**EDIT:** Just checked that using `dvipdfmx` works fine, so this might be a pointless question

Comment: You might want to mention exactly how you get the image you show. (I get the same using latex+dvips+gv)

Comment: Also converting the `.ps` to `.pdf` using `ps2pdf` also give the bad result on my system

Comment: On a MiKTeX system, with Ghostview I have the same problem. However, the .pdf directly produced by `dvipdfmx` is OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This due to an error in the map-file `sansmathfonts.map`.

The map contains entries like this

```
   cmsssy10 cmsssy10 <cmsssy10.pfb
```

The middle argument should be the font name. But looking in  cmsssy10.pfb one can see that the font name is not `cmsssy10`:

```
  /FontName /ComputerModernSans-Regular10pt def
```

While pdflatex normally ignores such errors dvips is much more picky and all sort of curious things can happen.

When I correct in psfonts.map the entry to

```
  cmsssy10 ComputerModernSans-Regular10pt <cmsssy10.pfb
```

dvips gives the correct output. You should report the bug to the author of sansmathfonts. He/she should either correct the map files or the font names in the pfb.

### Edit

The problem has been corrected. With a new version of the package everything is fine.