# Size of large symbols with sansmathfonts

Tags: math-mode, symbols, sansmathfonts

I'm having some issues with the `sansmathfonts` large operators. The code

```
\documentclass{article} 

% \usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{sansmathfonts}

\begin{document}

abc $\displaystyle\int$ \footnotesize abc $\displaystyle\int abc$

\end{document}
```

with both packages commented out yields

[image]

The letters are indeed smaller, but the integral remains the same. This can be "fixed" by loading `amsmath`

[image]

However, when loading also `sansmathfonts` the problem comes back

[image]

I gave a look at `omxcmssex.fd` but things like `\DeclareFontShape` are sadly still quite a mystery to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is very similar to [Ugly alignment (size of square root symbol) with Latin Modern at 12pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375823/4427)

Declare the OMX font to be scalable instead of “fixed”.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{cmssex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmssex}{m}{n}{
  <-7.5> cmssex7
  <7.5-8.5> cmssex8
  <8.5-9.5> cmssex9
  <9.5-> cmssex10
}{}

\begin{document}

abc $\displaystyle\int abc$ \footnotesize abc $\displaystyle\int abc$

\end{document}
```

[image]

### UPDATE 2019-06-12

The 2019-06-10 release of `sansmathfonts` fixes the issue. Now, with

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}

\begin{document}

abc $\displaystyle\int abc$ \footnotesize abc $\displaystyle\int abc$

\end{document}
```

you get the same output as above.

Comment: I actually suspected that and I'm pretty sure I had tried that out...

Comment: @campa The difference is “been there, done that”. `;-)`

Comment: @campa Actually something better can be done. Added the available sizes.

Comment: @egreg is that an issue in one of the sansmathfonts? because I did get the maintainer to update all the associated fd files. I can write the maintainer to get this updated.

Comment: @daleif It uses `<->sfixed*cmssex10`.

Comment: @egreg should it be gen instead of sfixed*? or should it be like you did in your answer?

Comment: @daleif With `gen` you only get fixed sizes; it was useful in the olden times, when `pk` files were necessary. Nowadays it doesn't seem appropriate. One can discuss *ad libitum* about the intervals.

Comment: @egreg I'll ask the maintainer to make them in the same manner as the others when they we changed, accompanied wiht the OPs MWE.

Comment: @daleif [It's not the first time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353603/82917) I had issues with `sansmathfonts`. That time I contacted the maintainer personally. I believe she'll remember me `:-)`

Comment: @campa I had the maintainer update the fd files a few months ago, but apparently missed that one. I think this font works a lot better with beamer than the normal beamer math setup

Comment: @campa You'll be glad to know that the new version of `sansmathfonts` fixes the issue.